# What anime does this girl greeting the KFC mascot come from?

Tags: miyuki

[image: Image about the colonel statue being salutated by a girl, old anime perhaps, don't know the source, can anyone find it?]

Hi guys/girls, I'm looking for the source of this Gif, can't find it anywhere, obviously its from an old anime, maybe someone who has seen old subbed things will be able to find it at glance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This scene is from **[Miyuki](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2231/Miyuki)**, an anime adaptiation of the Manga by the same name written by Adachi:

[image]

**Synopsis:**

> Wakamatsu Masato lives with his step-sister, Miyuki, whom he does not have blood relationship with. Their father is always working oversea and left the two of them living by themselves in Toukyou. Miyuki is cute, nice, sensitive and very popular among guys around Masato. Masato has a girlfriend at school whose name is Kajima Miyuki, who is pretty and gentle, the ideal dream of every highschool boy.